# Is it possible to rename a property in Apache AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

The documentation does not mention much about it. I was working on a blog post where I need to rename a property to something else.
Does Apache AGE support renaming properties? There is no information on the page of SET clause either [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/set.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can achieve that through using two consecutive operations [**SET** with the new property name then **REMOVE** the old property name]

Example:

1- Query the existing data (vid is the property which will be changed)

```
 SELECT * 
FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:Person{vid:1}) return a
$$) as (e agtype);
                                                e                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 1, "title": "backend"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

2- SET THEN REMOVE

```
 SELECT * 
FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:Person{vid:1}) set a.vcid = a.vid remove a.vid
$$) as (e agtype);
 e 
---
(0 rows)
```

3- Test old query to check if vid still existing or not

```
 SELECT * 
FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:Person{vid:1}) return a                       
$$) as (e agtype);
 e 
---
(0 rows)
```

4- Test the new changed property

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:Person{vcid:1}) return a
$$) as (e agtype);
                                                 e                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vcid": 1, "title": "backend"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename a property in AGE, you have to use `SET` and `REMOVE`. set the current property to a new property and then remove current/old property within the cypher query. An example is given below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graphname', $$
    MATCH (n:Label) SET n.newprop = n.oldprop REMOVE n.oldprop
$$) as (n agtype);
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the official documentation, Apache AGE doesn't support renaming properties.

A workaround for this is to create a new property with the name you want and then move the data over from the older property.

Comment: Please show an example. It looks like this is saying the same thing as the other answers.